# How to set customize imageView ID?

Tags: android

I have several image-views in my xml file, i need to initialize and use them dynamically.

[image: see the image]

In the image currentParam.x and y are coordinates.
Is there any way to do this task.

Comment: see `Resources#getIdentifier()`

Answer (score 0):

To get a resource `id` out of the resource name, use this code below. i tested in my project. working like a charm.

```
String packageName = getPackageName();
String tempCurrent = "square" + String.valueOf(currentParams.x+1) + String.valueOf(currentPrams.y+1);
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("square", "id", packageName);
currentImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(resId);
```